# saving request and response in the csv in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have script that I am using to create users for my Load test. In the request, I am passing `username` along with other parameters and the response will be `userid`.

What I want to save `username` from the request and `userid` from the response in the same csv file, such that output looks something like:

> username1,userid1
>   username2,userid2

Is this possible in jMeter?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose login is in csv and extracted using csv dataset, so:

- add a regexp extractor or Css/Jquery extractor to extract the variables userid
- then use a JSR223 Post Processor with groovy and write in it the code that writes the 2 variables, you can access them using:

> vars.get("userid")

and

> vars.get("login")

if your variables are called userid and login

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add a line `sample_variables=username,userid` (without spaces!)  to bin/jmeter.properties. Then you can use any of standard listeners to save csv log file. Your jmeter variables ${username} and ${userid} would be there as new columns.